# Click through questions hiding the previous one each time using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 5 questions that I want to click through. I only want one question on the page at a time. There are back and next buttons below each question. But the jQuery I have worked on the first question, but fails after that. What am I doing wrong?

HTML

```
<div id="one">
  <span>What is your first name?</span>
  <div>
    a href="#" id="back">back</a>
    a href="#" id="next">Next</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="two">
  <span>What is your last name?</span>
  <div>
    a href="#" id="back">back</a>
    a href="#" id="next">Next</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="three">
  <span>How old are you?</span>
  <div>
    a href="#" id="back">back</a>
    a href="#" id="next">Next</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="four">
  <span>What is your favourite colour?</span>
  <div>
    a href="#" id="back">back</a>
    a href="#" id="next">Next</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>  
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#two").hide();
    $("#three").hide();
    $("#four").hide();
    $("#next").click(function () {
      $("#one").hide();
      $("#two").show();
    });
  });
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#next").click(function () {
      $("#two").hide();
      $("#three").show();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Please note you can not have multiple elements with the same id. Id should always be unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem is You cant give same `id` to your elements. Id is used to make element uniqeu. You can use `class` for same type elements.

Your second problem is syntax error before `a` tag elements.

As as way you first can hide all elements using `class` attribute and show spesific element with `id` attribute.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".question").hide();
     $("#one").show();
   
  });
  function NextBack(id){
     $(".question").hide();
     $("#"+id).show();
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one"class="question">
  <span>What is your first name?</span>
  <div>
   <a href="#"onclick="NextBack('four')" class="back">back</a>
   <a href="#"onclick="NextBack('two')" class="next">Next</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="two"class="question">
  <span>What is your last name?</span>
  <div>
   <a href="#"onclick="NextBack('one')" class="back">back</a>
   <a href="#"onclick="NextBack('three')" class="next">Next</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="three"class="question">
  <span>How old are you?</span>
  <div>
   <a href="#"onclick="NextBack('two')" class="back">back</a>
   <a href="#"onclick="NextBack('four')" class="next">Next</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="four"class="question">
  <span>What is your favourite colour?</span>
  <div>
  <a href="#" onclick="NextBack('three')" class="back">back</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="NextBack('one')" class="next">Next</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you can use dom element to hide and show

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".question").hide();
     $("#one").show();
   
  });
$(".back").click(function(e) {
   var id=e.target.closest(".question").previousElementSibling.getAttribute("id");
   if(id){
     $(".question").hide();
     $("#"+id).show();
   }
    
});

$(".next").click(function(e) { 
   var id=e.target.closest(".question").nextElementSibling.getAttribute("id");
   if(id){
    $(".question").hide();
     $("#"+id).show();
   }  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one"class="question">
  <span>What is your first name?</span>
  <div>
   <a href="#" class="back">back</a>
   <a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="two"class="question">
  <span>What is your last name?</span>
  <div>
   <a href="#"class="back">back</a>
   <a href="#"class="next">Next</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="three"class="question">
  <span>How old are you?</span>
  <div>
   <a href="#"class="back">back</a>
   <a href="#"class="next">Next</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="four"class="question">
  <span>What is your favourite colour?</span>
  <div>
  <a href="#" class="back">back</a>
  <a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you are having multiple elements with the same `id`, `id`'s should always be unique.

also please note that you forgot the `<` infront of your links (`a`)

You can also achieve it in a simple way like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".questiontwo,.questionthree,.questionfour").hide();
  $(".next").click(function() {
    var current = $(this).closest("[class*=question]");
    var next = current.next("[class*=question]");
    if (next.length == 1){
      current.hide();
      next.show();
    }
  });
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".questiontwo,.questionthree,.questionfour").hide();
  $(".next").click(function() {
    var current = $(this).closest("[class*=question]");
    var next = current.next("[class*=question]");
    if (next.length == 1){
      current.hide();
      next.show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="questionone">
  <span>What is your first name?</span>
  <div>
    <a href="#" class="back">back</a>
    <a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="questiontwo">
  <span>What is your last name?</span>
  <div>
    <a href="#" class="back">back</a>
    <a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="questionthree">
  <span>How old are you?</span>
  <div>
    <a href="#" class="back">back</a>
    <a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="questionfour">
  <span>What is your favourite colour?</span>
  <div>
    <a href="#" class="back">back</a>
    <a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
  </div>
</div>
```